# How to enable NodeJS source maps in LocalStack?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, source-maps, localstack

Is it possible for LocalStack to use NodeJS source maps?

I have uploaded the `index.js.map` file with the minificed lambda's source code `index.js` file and also set the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable to `--enable-source-maps`; however, I still get error messages with the line number of the minified `index.js` file.

I ran this command to confirm the environment variables were correct.

```bash
awslocal lambda get-function-configuration --function-name "my-lambda"
```

```json
"Environment": {
    "Variables": {
        "APPSYNC_URL": "http://localhost:4566/appsync-api/xxxx/graphql",
        "AWS_REGION": "us-east-1",
        "NODE_ENV": "test",
        "NODE_OPTIONS": "--enable-source-maps"
    }
},
```